# Identify supported video file format and convert accordingly

Tags: video, conversion, codec, file-types, mjpeg

I have a small video advertising device that I want to change the video on.

Inside it has an AK2117 multimedia chip. The documentation states it has a WMA Decoder (bit rate 32-384 Kbps, 8-48KHZ), Digital Voice Recording (ADPCM) and Integrated Motion JPEG video decoder (up to 30fps@QCIF+).

My knowledge of all this is very rudimentary, but I believe I'm using the above settings when converting my video using Convertio. I've tried several times and I'm still getting an error message saying "Incorrect File Format" on the player.

I've also analysed the original video file (i.e. the advert included with the player) using GSpot:

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Can anyone help point me in the right direction to convert a video file to the correct settings to play on this player?

TIA

Comment: I'm currently fiddling around with a Ak2117D and was wondering if you ever found a solution as to what the format and codec should be?